# Why can't i run nodejs app from package.json in shared web hosting?

Tags: node.js, hosting, web-hosting, package.json, shared-hosting

I can't run nodejs application from package.json in shared web hosting. It just runs the server.js or index.js file. *So is there any way to run scripts from package.json?*

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't change the entry point in shared web hosting. Second, you don't have control over shared hosted server to install node.js or even acces the actual directory in server. So no it's not possible do that without much control of the operating environment which I assume you are trying to deploy your app.

May I suggest an alternative to shared hosting, VPS hosting.
Virtual Private Server (VPS) is hosting that virtually mimics dedicated server environments within a shared server. VPS hosting is generally lower in cost than dedicated hosting but provides better reliability, security, and performance than shared hosting. **Moreover, users get root access to the server, giving them the freedom to install applications and make environment changes without having to go through the hosting provider**, as they would with shared hosting.

Comment: In my shared hosting there is a nodejs option. Can I host applications like strapijs there ?

Comment: if it does great!, checkout this article or read nodejs hosting doc provided by your shared hosting service provider https://medium.com/@pampas93/host-your-node-js-app-on-shared-hosting-go-beyond-localhost-73ab923e6691